# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint when saving recursive structure with Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-collections-ef-core

I'm getting an error

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint

when trying to call

```
_dbContext.Set<T>().Persist(_mapper).InsertOrUpdate(typeof(Category), model);
```

to save a recursive tree structure using Automapper.

I have these 2 data objects where the primary key is `CategoryId` and `ProjectId`.

```
public class CategoryTree  //My DTO
{
   public CategoryId {get;set;}
   public ProjectId {get;set;}
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<Categery> Categories {get; set;}
}

public class Category //My Entity
{
   public Guid CategoryId {get;set;}
   public Guid ProjectId {get;set;}
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<Categery> Categories {get; set;}
   public List<Topic> Topics {get; set;}
   public Guid ParentCategoryId {get; set;}
}
```

I've added the `Automapper.Collections` and the `Automapper.EntityFrameworkCore.Collection` and included the config for those in my mapper config

```
cfg.AddCollectionMappers();
cfg.UseEntityFrameworkCoreModel<AKSContext>();
```

I've tried both with and without setting an equality comparer

```
cfg.EqualityComparison((mod, ent) => (mod.CategoryId == ent.CategoryId && mod.ProjectId == ent.ProjectId))
```

Everything works fine on the first save that inserts the tree, and on the second save, the first node doesn't have any children and that one updates fine, but the second node throws the exception for a primary key violation of the first child.

In other words, it's able to detect that it's an update for the top level, but it assumes it's an insert for the children. I assume I'm missing something.

Comment: This may be the answer or just a workaround, but I flattened my tree and as long as I save it in the right order to avoid a foreign key violation that's working for me. Still curious if there is a better way.

Comment: While flatteningg the tree fixed the problem at the root object level, I'm now having the same the issue with objects in collection within the root. Edited the question to add the List<Topics> where I'm now getting the error.